# Monitoring multiple folders in one 'syncFolderItems' operation?

Tags: soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2007

Is it possible to monitor several folders in one 'syncFolderItems' operation?
I tried it, but It doesn't seem to work.
For example, this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Body>
    <SyncFolderItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
      <ItemShape>
        <t:BaseShape>Default</t:BaseShape>
      </ItemShape>
      <SyncFolderId>           
 <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="drafts"/>
 <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="inbox"/>


 </SyncFolderId>

      <MaxChangesReturned>500</MaxChangesReturned>
    </SyncFolderItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

doesn't work :(

is it possible? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I know this is very old question but, still it is important for other user so i am answering.
**No it is not Possible**
SyncFolderId can have one child tag FolderID or DistinguishedFolderID

```
<SyncFolderId>
   <FolderId/>
</SyncFolderId>
```

---

```
<SyncFolderId>
   <DistinguishedFolderId/>
</SyncFolderId>
```

reference link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/aa580296%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx